# In ubuntu intent-based API for text messages differentiate between various intents within a single message?

Tags: text-processing

I'm working on AI/Ml model to develop understand AI based intent detection for text messages. so in ubuntu system API for text messages differentiate between various intents within a single message?. can anyone help me with that?

Comment: No, we can not. AU is for asking about issues you face when using Ubuntu.  Not for asking for help coding new software. Tagging "12.04" is weird so is "ubuntu-one-api" in this context. Almost looks like this is auto generated.